# Calculating value of function at middle of interval, given integrals of the function on the interval.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was asked the following question :

> $$I = \int_0^1 xf(x) \,dx =\frac{1}{6}$$
>
> $$J = \int_0^1 (f(x))^2\,dx =\frac{1}{12}$$
>
> $$f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \ ? $$
>
> Here, $f(x)$ is a continuous function

**My try:**

I couldn't find a good starting point to solve the function. Firstly I tried to draw some graphs of a random function $xf(x)$ and $2(f(x))^2$ so that the area under the two curves is the same, but it didn't reach any conclusive point. Next, I tried using :

$$\int_0^{2a} f(x)\,dx = \int_0^a f(x) + f(a-x)\,dx$$

to get $\frac{1}{2}$ as one of the limits, but that just complicated things more, as I cannot comment much about $f(1-x)$.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:** It is given that the function is continuous.

Comment: Do you have any information about $f$?  For example, there is no hope of solving this problem if $f$ isn’t continuous.

Comment: @MichaelBurr $f$ is given to be continuous (see EDIT)

Comment: If you assume that $f(x)$ is a linear function, you get that $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x$ and $f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{4}$. This does not prove that $f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{4}$ is true in general however.

Comment: So far I cannot find a duplicate of this question. Where is this question from?

Comment: It's from a JEE question bank. AlthoughI I don't have solutions for it.

Comment: I am not convinced that there’s enough information.  Have you tried $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$?  Then the two integrals become two equations in three unknowns.  There are typically many solutions to such equations and I find it unlikely that they all have the same value at $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 13):

Compute $t \in \mathbb R$ such that

$$\int_0^1(f(x)-tx)^2 dx=0.$$

Since $f$ is continuous, we get $f(x)=tx.$

Comment: Thanks...this does give a solution, but what was your intuition behind choosing $tx$. Why not any other function like one @MichaelBurr suggested, or maybe even a trigonometric function, etc.

Comment: In $\int_0^1(f(x)-tx)^2 dx$ both of the integrals $\int_0^1f(x)^2 dx$ and $ \int_0^1 x f(x) dx$ occur.

Comment: Actually, it's necessary show also the unicity of the function $f$.

Comment: I am not so convinced that the information is sufficient. But to check it, it's up to you

Comment: Why the downvote  ???

Comment: @Revzora: we have $\int_0^1(f(x)-tx)^2 dx=0 \iff t=1/2.$ Hence $f(x)= \frac{1}{2}x$, thus $f(1/2)=1/4.$

Comment: ok... but maybe there exists an other function $g(x)\ne tx$ such that satisfy the condition of the topic with $g(1/2)\ne 1/4$

Comment: According to me it's necessary also show that $f(x)=tx$ it's the unique function satisfying the properties of the topic. Or show that $g(1/2)=1/4$ for all function $g(x)$ that satisfy that integral properties.

Comment: Suppose that $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, that $\int_0^1 xf(x) \,dx =\frac{1}{6}$ and that $\int_0^1 (f(x))^2\,dx =\frac{1}{12}$, then we derive that $\int_0^1(f(x)-\frac{1}{2}x)^2 dx=0.$ Since $(f(x)-\frac{1}{2}x)^2$ is continuous and $ \ge 0$ on $[0,1]$, we obtain that $(f(x)-\frac{1}{2}x)^2=0$ for all $x \in [0,1].$ Hence $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$ for all $x \in [0,1].$

Comment: You are right... i was confused.